# How do I use arrayformula on an IF formula?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I use arrayformula on this formula?

```
=if(H3-H2=0,I2+B3,B3)
```

I would like to apply it to the whole I column...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you are after, but try this:

```
=arrayformula(if((H3:H15)-(H2:H14)=0,I2+B3,B3))
```

If you want the same result as dragging down your formula use:

```
=arrayformula(if((H3:H15)-(H2:H14)=0,(I2:I15)+(B3:B15),(B3:B15)))
```

Here is a link to my test spreadsheet. Your formula is in L2 and mine is in M2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jC9Sku-w7BK7FmaRJ8BHXAn10d6JVl2mL_BV_XAT2E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This way of using array formula does not give the same result obtained by dragging down the formula on the other cells (which is the correct one).

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: The formula must be run inside the "I" column. Here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kiOzTsV_g7grFxp3d6vPtPNW4p_Mi5mGtYnY6m_tk8c/edit?usp=sharing (Second sheet)

Comment: There is no empty column in your sample sheet inside I. I inserted one and it worked fine. Can you show me an example of it not working?

Comment: Here it is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kiOzTsV_g7grFxp3d6vPtPNW4p_Mi5mGtYnY6m_tk8c/edit#gid=415324115 (secon sheet column I). Thank you.

Comment: OK, I see your problem. You can not refer to the column L inside the formula in column L. You will get the circular dependency error. That's just how it works.